# c:if tag is not working for scope

Tags: java, tags, struts, taglib

I am using Strtus 1.3. In that application I want to use a `<c:if>` tag:

```
<c:if test="${requestScope.regerr ne null}">
```

but when I am using jsp page give me a warning:

```
test does not support run time expression
```

and console I got an error

```
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: /Reg.jsp (line: 14, column: 0) According to TLD or attribute directive in tag file, attribute test does not accept any expressions
```

So how could I use with scope? In this I want to check whether in the request Scope regerr is null or not?

Comment: can you please post some code?

Comment: Try `<c:if test="${not empty requestScope.regerr}">`

Comment: In RegAction.java class I use this

    request.setAttribute("regerr", "You have been allready registered..");

and this request attribute I want to access in jsp page.

Comment: Please read the possible duplicate link provided.

Comment: same as it is i tried all the poossiblities

Comment: may be this a problem with jar file

Comment: yes after adding jstl1.1 and above its working.. Thanks Luiggi